# Why "hundreds and hundreds" instead of just "hundreds"?

Tags: repetition, quantifiers

What does one mean by "hundreds and hundreds"? 
What's the difference between "hundreds and hundreds" and "hundreds"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/and): "If **and** is used to ​join two words that are the same, it makes ​their ​meaning ​stronger".

> I have been waiting for hours and hours
>
> We laughed and laughed!
>
> The noise grew louder and louder.
>
> There were hundreds and hundreds of wellwishers.

It can also suggest a progression in time - the sound is getting progressively louder, or the wellwishers were arriving in large numbers, continuously.

It can be used for exaggeration, and should not always be taken literally, especially when used by children. Imagine a situation where little Johnny's favorite food is spaghetti. He had spaghetti on Thursday last week, and wants it again today.

> Mum, mum, can we have spaghetti for dinner? We haven't had it for ages and aaaaaages!

Looking at published usages of reduplicative and-numbers, all of them seem 
popular with religious fanatics of all sects, with Christians scoring the only quadruple reduplicative - **millions and millions and millions and millions**. **scores and scores** was popular in the 19th century and is often used in historical novels set in that period. **dozens and dozens** has quite varied usage, and is gaining in popularity.

**Hundreds and hundreds** features mainly in books targeted at children. The 
 majority of the remaining usages are quotes from uneducated people.

This suggests to me that a hundred is a kind of event-horizon for pre-numerate 
 or innumerate people, and **hundreds** could be used about any number that 
 they can't imagine counting- and for a five year old, that's probably not very 
 many at all.

Adults who can count and have some idea of the actual numbers would be more likely to use **a couple of hundred** for anything between one and three hundred, and **a few hundred** or **several hundred** for anything between three and nine hundred.

Putting this all together, it seems likely that many usages of **hundreds and hundreds** are hyperbolic, and bear little relation to real numbers.

Comment: So, by 'stronger'  hundreds and hundreds is necessarily more in quantity  than hundreds? Or it just makes the expression stronger, like for emphasis or scare tactics? Anyway to me, hundreds  and hundreds  means a significantly greater amount than hundreds. Or the idea of waves and waves of hundreds. Anyway, just my two and two cents.

Comment: This is meta  but it seems a major weakness of SE that no interaction between asker and answers is expected or wanted. We don't even know if the OP voted on any of these answers  or was helped at all, has his question answered.

Comment: Nah I won't @Java I just have to blow off steam every once in a while. I'm not a devotee of the politics and working rationale of this site. I really just try to help the people who ask the questions, here and on other sites. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

"Hundreds and hundreds" has almost exactly the same meaning as "hundreds", it is just used for emphasis. "Hundreds" means at least 200, but "hundreds and hundreds" means at least 400 - neither of these is used to refer to any specific amount beyond that.
They are used interchangeably, although 'hundreds and hundreds' is a bit less formal.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been said before, "hundreds and hundreds" is used for emphasis. However, you could also use "hundreds upon hundreds" for a more literary perspective. Both could also mean that after each hundreds (possibly fallen soldier), there is always hundreds more waiting, whereas with "hundreds", once those hundreds are done, it's over.

Answer (score 0):

Its a way of emphasizing the quantity. Consider the following sentence :

> The army had **hundreds** of blood thirsty warriors.

It is pretty clear that the army had a multiple-of-hundred warriors (roughly). This could mean 200 or 300 or 500 warriors, or any multiple of 100 (not strictly a multiple, but ideally). Now imagine if the sentence was framed as :

> The army had **hundreds and hundreds** of blood thirsty warriors.

Now this emphasis is far more terrifying than the former. The whole concept of picturing the army in your mind changes when the sentence is re-framed like this. Its a word play. The meaning actually doesn't change.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'hundreds' could be used to refer to a quantity of 100 000. That would be better said as 'thousands'.

Comment: I agree with @Rex - I think this answer could be improved if you at least took one zero off that big number. Though not technically incorrect, not many would refer to 100,000 of something as "hundreds."

Comment: I've made required edits.